# Visual Basic Clipboard Manipulation

Tags: vb.net, string, variables, clipboard, literals

To get straight to the point. I've got 3 buttons. Each button sends a lengthy message to the clipboard where I can then paste it in another window.

The messages are currently being stored in a string with some sort of XML hack:

```
ResponseMessage = <a>This is string this is istr

Welcome To PoodleSchool
This is a string
Hello
There is no one like me<a>.Value
```

Now I need to replace a piece of the string, for example, "PoodleSchool" with maybe "DogSchool" or whatever the variable is. How can I change the string and then send it to clipboard?

The variable will be based on a textbox placed on the applications form. Then when the button is pressed, the message must be copied to clipboard with the correct name taken from the textbox variable.

Any takers?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using "<%= VARIABLE %>" in the middle of the string! Thank you Internet!